# Calling same function from other two function

Tags: iphone, ios, methods, ios6

I am want to know if there is any way to call a same function from other two functions.

Like, say ..fucntion1 calls the MainFunction and then after function1 has done using the main function, function2 should call the MainFunction.

I have learned that this can be achieved using NSOperation queues ? But that is for asynchronous execution, I do not want that.

Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Any help will be truly appreciated, Thank you for your time. :)

Comment: By default they will go for execution synchronous execution, I assume.

Comment: So, If we call the MainFunction using conventional ways, it should work fine? But however, this is not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dispatch_sync()`. It's part of the [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) API.

Comment: Made some search, I dont quite understand how to use it. Can you explain with a very basic and simple example ?

Answer (score 0):

Use below method, it may helps you

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:(SEL) withObject:(id)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help ..! I ended up using delegates to solve this issue, I inserted a delegate callback, which gives me a callback after the first function completes using the MainFucntion and after getting the callback i called that MainFucntion using the secondMethod.